# How is "Between the Evenings" Interpreted in the Aramaic Targums?

Tags: shabbat, passover, calendar, pentateuch-chumash, targumin

> **Shemot 12:6, (Exodus)** - והיה לכם למשמרת עד ארבעה עשר יום לחדש הזה ושחטו אתו כל קהל עדת־ישראל ***בין הערבים [Between the Evenings]***׃

Could someone help provide references from the Targums, (Jonathan, Onkelos, Neofiti, Septuagint, etc), and help translate how this phrase is interpreted in them?

Comment: I'm not sure how ביני שימשתא is more clear than the original בין הערבים

Comment: @DoubleAA - Thanks. My intent was: **A.)** To determine if `ביני שימשתא` was simply an idiomatic version of `בין הערבים` - semantically synonymous - proven by a consistent translation throughout the Tanakh;  **B.)** Or - Determine if there is a semantic difference between the two, which would be shown if the Tanakh itself exhibited both expressions, to mean different things; **C.)** Since the answer below shows that the expressions are used interchangeably, your point makes sense, *(A)*.  And, since the Tanakh seems to have no instance of `ביני שימשתא`, the second theory *(B)* seems disproved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sefaria.org website only has a couple of choices:

> **[T"Onkelos](http://www.sefaria.org/Onkelos_Exodus.12?lang=bi):** וִיהֵי לְכוֹן לְמַטְרָא עַד אַרְבְּעָא עַסְרָא יוֹמָא לְיַרְחָא הָדֵין וְיִכְּסוּן יָתֵהּ כֹּל קְהָלָא כְנִשְׁתָּא דְיִשְׂרָאֵל ***בֵּין שִׁמְשַּׁיָא***;
>
> **[T"Neofiti](http://cal1.cn.huc.edu):** ביני שמשותא;
>
> **[T"Yonatan](http://www.sefaria.org/Targum_Jonathan_on_Exodus.12?lang=bi):** And it shall be bound and reserved for you until the fourteenth day of this month, that you may not know the fear of the Mizraee when they see it; and ye shall kill him according to the rite of all to congregation of the assembly of Israel, between the suns ***[ביני שימשתא]***;
>
> [T"Septuagint](http://en.katabiblon.com/us/index.php?text=LXX&book=Ex&ch=12&interlin=on#v6): πρὸς ἑσπέραν [Towards the evening];

Both seems to have the same idea, bein shimshaya, between the suns.

There is also the Tafsir Rasag:

> [Tafsir Rasag](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.12.6?lang=bi&p2=Tafsir_Rasag,_Exodus.12.6&lang2=en) : יכון ענדכם מחפוט֗א אלי אליום אלראבע עשר מן הד֗א אלשהר פיד֗בחה ג֗וק ג֗מאעה בני אסראיל בין אלגרובין

Comment: @elikakohen the Shadal summarizes as  אין ספק כי הוא בין השמשות כדעת הקראים וראב"ע, כי כתוב בין הערבים תאכלו בשר (למטה י"ו י"ט), וכתוב ויהי בערב ותעל השלו, וכן תרגם אונקלוס בין שמשיא

Comment: @Danno - Thank you for the help.  I have not found a translation for Shadal's explanation; **B.)** Should I just post another question - asking to clarify why/when the terms are synonymous (or not)?

Comment: My best understanding of the Shadal is his contention that there can be no doubt but that the meaning is "between the suns" which correlates with the understandings of commentators like the Ibn Ezra because one location uses the word-root e-r-v to point to one time and another uses the word to refer to another time, and therefore the Onkelos translates it as bein shimshaya

Comment: I don't understand what was your safek,  and what was the element which was lead you to decide.